# How to require .el file when working with common lisp?

Tags: file, emacs, shared-libraries, common-lisp, slime

An additional library **mylibrary.el** for emacs (v 26.3) was added
to ***load-path*** and is ***autoloaded*** in my **init.el file**.

The library is also listed under my installed packages in emacs (*M-x list-packages*) and is provided through *(provide 'mylibrary)* in **mylibrary.el**.

The file can be executed in emacs with *M-x
mylibrary* but cannot be required in my slime-repl session.

```
CL-USER> (require 'mylibrary)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-INT:EXTENSION-FAILURE
 "Don't know how to ~S ~A." {1007A5F073}>.

CL-USER> (require 'asdf)
NIL
```

any ideas why I can require asdf and not my library?

Comment: .el are typically elisp files, so they are not processed by Common Lisp. Is it part of some package that also has .lisp files?

Comment: What is the library supposed to do (without entering in too much detail)? Do you want the buffer that displays the REPL to be configured a certain way (Emacs Lisp side) or do you want the Lisp process to execute code in Emacs?

Comment: the library provides a widget. it is an elisp file because it requires also the library widget which is also an elisp file. however I want to process the input given by the widget user in a lisp file.

Comment: UI code lives in the Frontend, Emacs, so you shouldn't need to have a concept of widget in the backend (CL). You can pass data from Emacs to Lisp using a format of your choice (sexp, or even json, etc.). This decoupling allows you for example to support different interfaces (cli, http, etc)

Comment: There seem to be either wrong assumption, or some relevant piece of information missing. Is this a public code you can point to? If not, can you discuss with whoever provided that to you?

Answer (score 2):

When running Slime to execute Lisp code from Emacs, there are two separate interpreters: the one in Emacs that interprets Emacs Lisp (Elisp), and the one in your Common Lisp (CL) implementation that is executed in a separate process:
*Slime is written in Emacs Lisp and connects to a server called Swank, implemented in Common Lisp*.

Emacs Lisp shares a lot of similarities with Common Lisp, but is a different language. It would be surprising if a library written in Elisp could be interpreted without modification in CL.

You can require `asdf` because it is written in CL and available as a built-in in most implementations.

Note that from the Lisp side of things, you can call `(swank:eval-in-emacs emacs-expr)` to ask Emacs to run some Emacs Lisp code for you (provided you turn the security flag to false in Emacs). I use this to visit some files from the Lisp process but this is not necessarily what you need here (depending on what your library does, it might be possible to find an equivalent one in CL).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Common Lisp code has the file ending `.lisp`.

Emacs Lisp code has the file extension `.el`.

Racket (originally Scheme) code has the file extension `.rkt`.

Scheme code has the file extension `.scm`.

Clojure code has the file extension `.clj`.

ClojureScript code has the file extension `.cljs`.

(There are some more Lisps but these are the main ones).

These are different languages / lisp dialects, though they are all from the Lisp language family.

They need different compilers and interpreters. Therefore, you can't cross-exchange codes from one lisp dialects to the other.
Although, if you know the dialects it might not be too difficult for you
to translate them into the other language.

And sometimes (Common Lisp and Scheme) they have even different implementations with slight implementation-specific differences.
Common Lisp:

- SBCL
- ABCL
- CLISP
- ECL
- Franz Lisp
- CMUCL
  ...

Scheme:

- MIT/GNU Scheme
- Chez Scheme
- Chicken
- GNU Guile
- Gauche
  ...

implementations with varying implementation details.

Only with Clojure, ClojureScript and Rackt you can be sure that they have just one main/official implementation.

Comment: Incidentally, I think Racket is an important implementation of Scheme, since Racket is a superset of Scheme.